# How to protect from new Javascript Injection technique that doesn't use eval()?

Tags: appsec, web-application, xss, javascript

There is a new Javascript injection technique that is generating chatter on the forums mentioned [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/196544/Javascript-Injection-at-its-Finest-without-even-us.aspx#alternate1)

Here is the code sample:

```
String.prototype.code = function(){ return (new Function('with(this) { return ' + this + '}' )).call({}); };
var s = 'alert("hello!");'
s.code();
```

What infrastructure components need to be updated (if any) to monitor and protect from this class of exploit?

**For example:**

I'm under the impression that some DBA's scan their databases for evidence of a injection attack... this is almost a last-stand approach for mitigating a poorly written application in a distributed enterprise.

When I last worked with Microsoft on a JS Injection attack, the developer in India didn't properly verify form input.  This caused our client's database to be littered with Javascript code that executed on the client.  Microsoft's response was to search the database for pre-defined strings that are commonly used in attacks.

I'm *assuming* that there are products or sensors that monitor SQL or HTTP traffic for obvious js-malware.  If I take my assumption a step further, those devices need to have the signature updated for this vector.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its all XSS,  its not proper to call it "JavaScript Injection".  The XSS vector you are talking about isn't new,  and its an interesting one.   XSS is an **output** problem.  If you perform the same input validation on all input you'll still have problems with XSS.  If you encode or strip all `<` `>` characters for every input variable you'll still have huge problems with xss.  This is because XSS is highly dependent on where the variable is being printed to the page.

This line of code is safe:

```
var x='alert(123)'
```

However,  it can be exploitable if the attacker has access to single quotes `'` .   For instance if the attacker had a request like `?x=';alert(123);`,  then he would be able to break out of the quote marks and execute javascript.   The solution is to encode all quote marks as well.   In php you can use `htmlspecialchars($var,ENT_QUTOES);`

But here is the real kicker,  even this function can't stop all XSS.  It will stop about ~90% of xss.  But even after a `htmlspecialchars($var,ENT_QUTOES);` you can still run into problems with [DOM based xss](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS)  and XSS via [event handlers](https://blog.whitehatsec.com/tag/xss/).

So whats the **real solution**?  Test your code!   Use a free vulnerability scanning service like [Sitewatch](https://sitewat.ch/) or an open source tool like [Wapiti](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wapiti/).  These tools know all of the strange rules for XSS, and it will be able to find these violations in your application.   [Google uses Sitewatch](http://www.google.com/corporate/halloffame.html).

Comment: Thanks Rook... I just expanded the question to cover the aspect of IT Security I'm referring to.

Comment: Escaping all js/html in the database just doesn't make sense,  you don't know how the data is going to be used,  and there for you don't know how to properly sanitize it.

Comment: LOVE the Sitewatch link!!! (and other interesting js approaches) Thanks!

Comment: Also appreciate the reinforcement of a development practice of "where to encode/decode?".  It makes logical sense; I'd like to assert this practice in our environment, please share a Patterns and Practices link if you know of any.

Comment: @makerofthings Cool,  I'm glad you enjoyed my post.   To be honest i don't know of a good paper on patters and practices,  I might have to write one.

Comment: IMHO - This stuff should be hooked into ASP.NET MVC by default as you describe... not sure if it is already.

Comment: OWASP has a very good reference on encoding practices. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: There are also libraries that do proper context-specific encodings, e.g. MS WPL/AntiXSS and OWASP's ESAPI.

Comment: @AviD♦  and HTMLPurifer for php.   However this is a complex problem to solve as evident by the CVE numbers issued for these projects. This is made much worse by the fact that no two browsers will behave identically,  especially when it comes to js event handlers.

Comment: @Rook, agreed. My point was that these libs offer a Javascript-encoding method (JavascriptEncode() and encodeForJavascript(), respectively), that can help generically prevent the problem (IF used correctly....)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand what is so different about this technique than the general type of <strike>injection</strike> cross site scripting.

If this has gone so far and you happen to allow arbitrary JavaScript code to be injected and executed on your site, you're asking for trouble either way, no matter the technique. Try checking your site for most common [**XSS vulnerabilities**](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html).

I'm sorry if I'm missing something here, please correct me if I didn't get the big picture here (as I feel that way).

Comment: will revise and expand the question..